# How to add swift unit tests to an Xcode project of type "bundle"?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

MacOS 12.5, Xcode 13.4.1

I'm hoping to add swift-based unit tests to an existing project that is Mach-O type "Bundle" (`com.apple.product-type.bundle`) and acts as a plugin to a third project. Unfortunately I get linking errors when trying to run the unit test bundle such as below.

```
Underlying Error: The bundle “SOExample Unit Tests” couldn’t be loaded. The bundle couldn’t be loaded. Try reinstalling the bundle. dlopen(/Users/n8henrie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SOExample-fpwfambnggoejceucflywazoligm/Build/Products/Debug/SOExample Unit Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/SOExample Unit Tests, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_$s9SOExample3FooCACycfC)
  Referenced from: '/Users/n8henrie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SOExample-fpwfambnggoejceucflywazoligm/Build/Products/Debug/SOExample Unit Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/SOExample Unit Tests'
  Expected in: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/xctest')
```

I'm using `@testable import`, have `testability` set to `yes`, and am setting the `Bundle loader` to the bundle's executable.

I've created an example project to demonstrate the issue at https://github.com/n8henrie/so-xcode-unittest-example.git. To create it, I just made a new Xcode project of type "Bundle", added `File.swift` with `class Foo` and method `bar()`, then added a new target -> unit test bundle, which basically tests that it can create a `Foo` and run `bar()`. I then add the main target as the `Bundle loader` and commit changes. One should be able to test as follows:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/n8henrie/so-xcode-unittest-example.git
$ cd so-xcode-unittest-example/
$ xcodebuild -scheme "SOExample Unit Tests" test
```

It currently fails with the above "couldn't be loaded" error. It looks like the symbols are there (I think -- I'm new to this):

```
$ nm -gU SOExample
0000000000003d78 T _$s9SOExample3FooC3barSSyF
0000000000003f34 S _$s9SOExample3FooC3barSSyFTq
0000000000003e14 T _$s9SOExample3FooCACycfC
0000000000003f3c S _$s9SOExample3FooCACycfCTq
0000000000003e4c T _$s9SOExample3FooCACycfc
0000000000003e70 T _$s9SOExample3FooCMa
0000000000008090 D _$s9SOExample3FooCMm
0000000000003f00 S _$s9SOExample3FooCMn
00000000000080c8 D _$s9SOExample3FooCN
0000000000003dd8 T _$s9SOExample3FooCfD
0000000000003db4 T _$s9SOExample3FooCfd
```

If I change the `Mach-O` type to `Dynamic Library`, `Static Library`, or `Relocatable Object File`, the linking succeeds and the example test passes.

**NB:** In this specific toy case I can also get the tests to pass while leaving the `Mach-O` type as `bundle` if I add `SOExample Unit Tests` to the target membership for `File.swift`; however this doesn't work for my real-world scenario (and I think employing `@testable import` should make this unnecessary, especially as it works with other Mach-O types).

Is there a way to run my unit tests:

- leaving the `Mach-O` type as `Bundle`
- without modifying "target membership"

?

Relevant links (without solutions that I've found)

- [Xcode unit tests for plugin bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491495/xcode-unit-tests-for-plugin-bundles)
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128330

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying something related: I have code in a bundle that I want to test, but I get link errors in the test target where it can't find the symbols I'm referencing in the bundle.

Comment: I ended up adding a separate target for the tests I think, but eventually got something that works well enough. Relevant commits here: https://github.com/quicksilver/plugin_template/commits/main

Comment: Sort of similarly, I ended up extracting the code I wanted to test out of the bundle and into a local Swift package. That makes it its own module and can be easily referenced from the unit test bundle.

Comment: If your code is open source, would you mind sharing a link?

Comment: It isn't, otherwise I'd be happy to.